# How to present data from a server into graph?

Tags: php, html, server

I'm try to make a project by using php:

The user input their health data and upload to the server.
Assume the server is local host.

Now how will I present those data to the user in graph?
What is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of getting the data back from the server to the client for presentation, two of them being sending them along with the HTML at page load, and AJAX. Personally, I would prefer latter, although it isn't as easy to realise (thinking of user identification/authorization and general security) since you need to set up an API.

To present the data on the user's frontend, there are again a variety of options. As a starting point, you can check out [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and [vis.js](http://visjs.org/). Just search for "js graph library" or something similar to find even more libraries.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side(back-end) language, not a front-end.

You will need to use JavaScript or its libraries for front-end development.

Take a look at [chartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/) which is open-source and free.